# Why is Baire space itself of 2nd category?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, notation

The definition of a Baire space is if given a countable collection of closed sets $\{ A_n \}_{n = 1} ^\infty$ with empty interiors, then $\bigcup_{n = 1} ^\infty A_n$ has an empty interior. A set of 2nd category is any set that is not of 1st category. The definition of being in the 1st category is if $X$ is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets.

It is said that any non-empty Baire space itself is of the 2nd category. However, it is not entirely clear to me why this is true. Does this come directly from the definition?

Comment: Yes - if $X$ were first category, then by definition of a Baire space, $X$ has an empty interior, which is absurd as the interior of $X$ is $X$.  (Though I guess technically $X = \emptyset$ is a Baire space...)

Comment: An aside.  Is $\varnothing$ a complete metric space?  Is it a Baire space?  Is it nowhere dense in itself?  Is it first in itself?

Comment: @GEdgar I am not sure if this was a trick question but this is what I think: Suppose $\emptyset$ has a well defined metric, then $\emptyset$ should be a complete metric space, since every Cauchy sequence in $\emptyset$ is trivially convergent, since there are no Cauchy sequences in $\emptyset$. Similarly, since $\emptyset$ has empty interior, it is a Baire space itself. For the same reason, it is nowhere dense in itself. I suppose it is also first in itself since $\emptyset$ is itself the union of empty sets. Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: @GEdgar Well okay, that is a bit odd actually. Then we have found a Baire space that is of 1st category. I suppose we have to assume Baire space to be nonempty for it to be of 2nd category. Otherwise, Baire Category Theorem doesn't work either. Since $\emptyset$ is complete, and hence by the Baire Category Theorem, it is a Baire space, and should be of the 2nd category.

Comment: This is why "nonempty" must be postulated in certain theorems about Baire category.  Fortunately, "nonempty" is, indeed, included in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, straight from that. Suppose $X$ were first category, $X = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} F_n$ where all $F_n$ are nowhere dense.

Then all $\overline{F_n}$ are closed sets with empty interior (by the definition of being nowhere dense) and obviously still $X = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \overline{F_n}$. But that then contradicts the Baire property of $X$ as $\text{int}(X)=X \neq \emptyset$. So $X$ is second category.